# sql query to get title name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck with sql query (SQL Server 2012), i have table called Function, that hold functionId and Title and 2nd table Function_Hierarchy, holding function_ids as combination of parent and child relations. I want to print title against each functionID....

[image]

[image]

here is my sql query,

```
SELECT B.Parent_Function_ID, A.Title AS Parent_Function, B.Child_Function_ID, A.Title AS   Child_Function
FROM [dbo].Functions AS A, [dbo].[Function_Hierarchy] AS B
WHERE B.Parent_Function_ID =A.Function_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Try This............

```
SELECT 
B.Parent_Function_ID,
 Parent_Function = (select top 1 A.Title from [dbo].Functions a  where  a.FunctionId = b.Parent_Function_id),
 B.Child_Function_ID,
   Child_Function = (select top 1 C.Title from [dbo].Functions c  where  c.FunctionId = b.Child_Function_id)
FROM [dbo].[Function_Hierarchy] AS B
```